# Decimal to Binary converter, console unresponsive

Tags: c

I'm trying a simple decimal to binary converter on C but the console isn't responding after entering the decimal number. Here's my code.

```
int convertDecimalToBinary(int n);


int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    convertDecimalToBinary(n);
    printf("%d in decimal = %d in binary", n, convertDecimalToBinary(n));
    return 0;
}

int convertDecimalToBinary(int n)
{
    int binaryNumber = 0;
    int remainder, i = 1;

    while (n!=0);
    {
        remainder = n%2;
        n /= 2;
        binaryNumber += remainder*i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    printf("%d\n",binaryNumber);
    return binaryNumber;

}
```

I'm not getting any error messages and I'm being prompted to enter a decimal number but after that it's unresponsive.

Comment: is it not just because the output is buffered and you're not printing a newline character?

Comment: What is decimal what is binary? I think that your algorithm is not doing what you think

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo which is causing an infinite while loop.
The semicolon at the end of while creates a while loop without a body.

```
while (n!=0);
    {
```

should be

```
while (n!=0)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

your program converts the number into something which is a very strange format.

7 will be 111 in decimal 60 will be 111100 in decimal. But you will overflow very soon as signed integer max value in this strange "binary in decimal" format is 1111111111 which id 1024 in the normal number

If you want to keep your strange format you must change to `unsigned long long` and you will be able to keep 11111111111111111111 or 1048575 in the "normal" decimal or convert the number to the string

any long long number to any base (almost - you need more characters for the digits) or simpler second function. It does not work with the minimum negative number

```
char *reverse(char *str);

const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

char *convert(long long number, char *buff, int base)
{
    char *result = (buff == NULL || base > strlen(digits) || base < 2) ? NULL : buff;
    char sign = 0;

    if (number < 0)
    {
         sign = '-';
        number = -number;
    }
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        *result = 0;
        do
        {
            *buff++ = digits[number % (base )];
            number /= base;
        } while (number);
        if(sign) *buff++ = sign;
        if (!*result) *buff++ = '0';
        *buff = 0;
        reverse(result);
    }
    return result;
}

char *convertToBIN(long long number, char *buff)
{
    char *result = buff;
    char sign = 0;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        sign = '-';
        number = -number;
    }
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        *result = 0;
        do
        {
            *buff++ = digits[number & 1];
            number >>= 1;
        } while (number);
        if (sign) *buff++ = sign;
        if (!*result) *buff++ = '0';
        *buff = 0;

        reverse(result);
    }
    return result;
}


char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char tmp;
    int len;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        {
            tmp = *(str + i);
            *(str + i) = *(str + len - i - 1);
            *(str + len - i - 1) = tmp;

        }
    }
    return str;
}
```